# Cytoscape installation assistance

Tags: cytoscape

I've tried installing and reinstalling both Cytoscape and Java. I'm kinda ignorant when it comes to these things so I would love detailed help.

macOS Catalina Version 10.15.4. Cytoscape 3.8.0 and Java 8 Update 251

Answer (score 0):

Cytoscape 3.8.0 requires Java 11 and won't run with Java 8.

-- scooter